# Why are my table cells empty when i try to add user input in it?

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to create a table to check upon my expanses but when i try to put my input inside my newly created table cells they are empty. Why is that so? I am wondering if it is because i am using the wrong format (like innerHTML instead of textContent) but everything i tried show either empty or "undefined"

```js
let dep = document.getElementById('denom').innerHTML;
let dat = document.getElementById('choixDate').innerHTML;
let mont = document.getElementById("montant").innerHTML;
let create = document.getElementById("ajouterDepense");
let liste = document.getElementById("listeDepense");

 function nouvelleLigne(){          
    var newline = liste.insertRow();
    var newCell = newline.insertCell();
    var newText = document.createTextNode(dep)
    newCell.appendChild(newText);
    var newCell1 = newline.insertCell(1);
    var newText1 = document.createTextNode(dat)
    newCell1.appendChild(newText1)
    var newCell2 = newline.insertCell(2);
    var newText2 = document.createTextNode(mont)
    newCell2.appendChild(newText2)
};
create.addEventListener('click', function() {       
    nouvelleLigne();               
});

document.getElementById('ajouterDepense').onclick = function(event){    
event.preventDefault()    
};
```

```css
table,
td{
    border: 1px solid #333;
    width: 100%
}

table{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Expanse.css">
<title>Expanse</title>
<script src="Expanse.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="content">
<h1> Expanse Tracker</h1>
<h2> Add a new Item</h2>
<form>
<label for="denom"> Nom de la dépense:</label>
<input type="text" id="denom" name="denom" required minlength="1" maxlength="40" size="40">
<br>
<br>
<label for="choixDate"> Date: </label>
<input type = "date" id="choixDate" name="choixDate" size="40">
<label for="montant"> Montant de la dépense:</label>
<input type="number" id="montant" name ="montant" size="30">
<button id="ajouterDepense" type="submit"> Ajouter Dépense </button>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<table id="listeDepense">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> Name </th>
<th> Date </th>
<th> Amount </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Vos dépenses vont ici!</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you are a) trying to read the input field values, before the fields have even been filled, and b) you are trying to read the field values in the wrong way as well. That's not done using `.innerHTML`, but `.value`.

Comment: and how can i change the timing of the value reading? because i thought the value reading would only happen when the event "click" would happen

Comment: This needs to happen _inside_ your function, because you always want the _current_ values of those fields, at the time the function executes.

Comment: oh wow thank you it was much easier than i tought... just a clarification, the -1 next to my question means that someone thought that my question was dumb or useless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let create = document.getElementById("ajouterDepense");
let liste = document.getElementById("listeDepense");

 function nouvelleLigne(){          
    var newline = liste.insertRow();
    var newCell = newline.insertCell();
    var newText = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('denom').value)
    newCell.appendChild(newText);
    var newCell1 = newline.insertCell(1);
    var newText1 = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('choixDate').value)
    newCell1.appendChild(newText1)
    var newCell2 = newline.insertCell(2);
    var newText2 =document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("montant").value*1);
    newCell2.appendChild(newText2)
};
create.addEventListener('click', function() {       
    nouvelleLigne();               
});

document.getElementById('ajouterDepense').onclick = function(event){    
event.preventDefault()    
};
```

```css
table,
td{
    border: 1px solid #333;
    width: 100%
}

table{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Expanse.css">
<title>Expanse</title>
<script src="Expanse.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="content">
<h1> Expanse Tracker</h1>
<h2> Add a new Item</h2>
<form>
<label for="denom"> Nom de la dépense:</label>
<input type="text" id="denom" name="denom" required minlength="1" maxlength="40" size="40">
<br>
<br>
<label for="choixDate"> Date: </label>
<input type = "date" id="choixDate" name="choixDate" size="40">
<label for="montant"> Montant de la dépense:</label>
<input type="number" id="montant" name ="montant" size="30">
<button id="ajouterDepense" type="submit"> Ajouter Dépense </button>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<table id="listeDepense">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> Name </th>
<th> Date </th>
<th> Amount </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Vos dépenses vont ici!</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```